# How to throw custom error from Velocity template using lambda

Tags: exception, aws-lambda, velocity, vtl

In my `Lambda` I am throwing custom error but from the `vtl` I am unable to get that when testing in Postman. In the postman I am keep getting message "A custom error was thrown from a mapping template." but I am expecting to get message and object from the custom class like `source` and `errors`

Here is my lambda function and custom error file
**Custom Error file**

```
export class ApiError extends Error {
  source: string
  args: string | undefined
  errors:  [{[key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string}}] | null | string

  constructor(source: string, methodArgs: string, errors: [{[key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string}}] | null | string ) {
    super();
    this.source =  source
    this.args = methodArgs
    this.errors = errors
  }
}


export const completeProcess: Handler = async (event: any): Promise<CustomResponse> => {
  const { customerId } = event.arguments.request as CustomRequest
  if (customerId === null) {
    throw new ApiError("completeProcess", JSON.stringify(event.arguments.request), "customerId missing")
  }
}
```

**Vtl file**

request.vtl

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "field": "getError",
        "arguments":  $utils.toJson($context.arguments)
    }
}
```

response.vtl

```
#if($context.error)
  $utils.error($context.result.source, $context.result.errors)
#else
  $utils.toJson($context.result)
#end
```

When running with above files I am keep getting response as

```
{
    "data": {
        "completeProcess": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "completeProcess"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": null,
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 2,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "A custom error was thrown from a mapping template."
        }
    ]
}
```